# PHP and a google translator API alternative

Tags: google-translate

Since Google is going to pull the plug out of their translator API (by the end of this year), Is there someone who already found a good (free or $) alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Try TranslateThis on http://translateth.is/...

Is very simple! To see the effects try this piece of code:

```
<!-- Begin TranslateThis Button -->

<div id="translate-this"><a style="width:180px;height:18px;display:block;" class="translate-this-button" href="http://translateth.is/">Translate</a></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://x.translateth.is/translate-this.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
TranslateThis();
</script>

<!-- End TranslateThis Button -->
```

Don't worry about the button aspect... You can customize it!

Answer (score 0):

Google is offering and alternative to website translation. Its the GOOGLE WEB ELEMENTS, and some code from the [google's web elements homepage](http://www.google.com/webelements/#!/translate) itself for translation

```
<!-- Google Translate Element -->
<div id="google_translate_element" style="display:block"></div><script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: "af"}, "google_translate_element");
};</script>
```

**Other alternatives:**
[Microsoft Translation Tools](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/tools/)
they offer [HTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512419.aspx), [SOAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512435.aspx) and [SDK](http://sdk.microsofttranslator.com/) interfaces for integration.

Comment: http://wizardsoweb.com/google-translate-api-deprecated-now-what-alternatives-are-here/2011/05/

Answer (score 0):

If you need just language detection, there is free API:

http://detectlanguage.com

It produces JSON output, just like Google Translate.